# 再帰的にべき乗を計算したいが、途中までしかできない

Tags: haskell

haskellでべき乗計算をしたいのですが、 現在は実行結果`["8"] ["2","^",3"]`までしか計算できません。 再帰的に`["256"]`を計算できるようにどのようにすればよいでしょうか

```
getLastThreeValues :: [String] -> [String]
getLastThreeValues [x, y, z] =  beki [x, y, z]
getLastThreeValues (_:xs) = getLastThreeValues xs

beki :: [String] -> [String]
beki [base, "^", exponent] = [show (read base ^ read exponent)]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ getLastThreeValues["2","^","2","^","3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんが最終的にやりたいことと合致しているかどうかわかりませんが、以下のように書くことはできます。

```haskell
beki :: [String] -> [String]
beki [x] = [x]
beki (base : "^" : exponent) = [show (read base ^ (read $ head $ beki exponent))]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ beki["2","^","2","^","3"]
```