# 実行結果["1","+","8","^","4"]なんですが、["1","+","512"]みたいにべき乗だけ計算した結果を返したいのですがどのようにプログラムを修正すればいいでしょうか？

Tags: haskell

```
beki :: Int -> Int -> Int
beki x y = x ^ y

beki2 :: [String] -> [String]
beki2 [x] = [x]
beki2 (base : "^" : exponent : xs) = show (beki (read base) (read exponent)) : beki2 xs
beki2 (x : xs) = x : beki2 xs
beki2 xs = xs

main = do
    print $ beki2 ["1", "+", "2", "^", "3","^", "2"]
```

**実行結果**

```
["1","+","8","^","4"]
```

Comment: なかなか回答がつかないときに同じ内容で質問を連投するのはおやめください。その代わりに、質問を [edit] して内容を改善できないかご検討ください。参考：[質問に誰も回答してくれない場合は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: その他の実行例
main = do
    print $ beki2 ["1", "+", "2", "^", "3","^", "2","-","4"]

 実行結果["1","+","512","-","4"]

Answer (score 0):

[前回の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95332/43506)の応用で書けます。
前回は再帰呼び出しの結果の`head`しか使いませんでしたが、今回は`tail`部(`ys`)を残すことで、べき乗以降の計算式を維持しています。

```hs
beki :: [String] -> [String]
beki [] = []
beki (base:"^":xs) = let exponent:ys = beki xs in show (read base ^ read exponent):ys
beki (x:xs) = x:beki xs
```